# Firebase Admob Ads not loading live Ads

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have added AdMob using Firebase.It is **not displaying live ads**, test ad is working fine. If I add `.addTestDevice("D9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");"` it is showing Test Ad.

I am following steps from [Google Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#create_a_new_project).

**Project Level - build.gradle**

```html
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

**App Level - build.gradle**

```html
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.1'
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```html
AdView mAdView;
AdRequest adRequest;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXX");

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```html
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id" />
```

**strings.xml**

```html
<string name="banner_id">ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX</string>
```

I am getting error in Logcat as

> W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
>
> W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

I also tried exporting the app for testing live ads, but failed. There are many answer that are telling that, Google might not have ads for my app, but there is no any log showing related to that.

Comment: Please give the proper banner_ad_unit_id in your application@Arth Tilva

Comment: having the same problem, any clue? @Arth Tilva

Comment: as you create new id, it takes time to load the ads for the app, need to wait for some time till google assigns some ads according to the app

Comment: At least for me that is not the problem, I created some Ad Units few weeks ago, but ads are not showing in a physical device, just the test ads in the emulator. I have one more question: If my app has been disabled for serving ads from AdMob (and I do not have the email), how can I know if it is disabled? @ArthTilva

Comment: Hi @ArthTilva , did you solved this problem? I'm getting the same issue for my app. I'm getting `Failed to load ad: 3` error.

Comment: Yes, @akshaybhange its just because ads are not served. there is no issue in code. if you get Failed to load ad: 3. just wait for google to start ads on your id.

Comment: I've been waiting for 3 weeks now. Please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253320/firebase-ads-are-not-loading-live-ads

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in your code

Add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of app level `build.gradle`.

**App Level - build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

make load `AdRequest` into `AdView` by adding `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);` after initializing ad `AdRequest` as below :

**MainActivity.java**

```
AdView mAdView;
AdRequest adRequest;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXXX");

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);` in your code.
You code will look like below:

```
 AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);//Required this line to load ad
```

See [Load the ad in the MainActivity class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#load_the_ad_in_the_mainactivity_class)

Answer (score 0):

**ADD PAYMENT INFO FROM ADMOB ACCOUNT AND WAIT FOR APPROVAL**

if the test ads are working fine then your implementation is correct, but there is an option of "Payment"  in the admob account which you need to fill. After filling up that form you will receive an email regarding the confirmation of payment details and  message indicating that whether your information was accepted by the admob team or not if yes then your live ads will be showing up.
but keep in mind that for the first few time the ad won't show up. it takes time to appear after the approval as well.
here is the code snippet for the error code to find what is going wrong

mAdView = (com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

```
    mAdView.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            if(errorCode==AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR)

            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "onAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    })
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

get the error code

ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR - Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.
ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST - The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.
ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR - The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.
ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL - The ad request was successful, but no ad was .

if you are getting error code 3 then after sometime you will get the ads  showing up after some time.

Answer (score -1):

Look at your string.xml in values folder. If your banner id is not like this
`<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>`
(this id ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 is for test ad only)
then replace it with your own banner ad unit id.